# Laravel 5 - Move Auth module in to a specific module

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I am creating a modular application using [nwidart](https://packagist.org/packages/nwidart/laravel-modules) package in Laravel 5.6. The command `php artisan make:auth` will create the necessary controllers and blades for authentication but I want to create a `User` module and move these things inside this module. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible . just use different controller and define the routes for the controller.and add use App\User; between Namespace and class Name.